# Does an SPRecycleBinItemType contain files

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a custom recycle bin report. I would like to know how to determine if a SPRecycleBinItemType of type folder contains any files in SP2010.

I have rummaged the OM and have not found a property to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any direct way to check if SPRecycleBinItemType of type folder contains any files as there is also no way to check from UI also.

But one think you can do is to check the size of the SPRecycleBinItemType item. As it would not give you size as 0 for empty folder but less the 1 KB. You can probably make a check on this property.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb spweb = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPRecycleBinQuery objQuery = new SPRecycleBinQuery();
                    objQuery.RowLimit = 100;
                    objQuery.OrderBy = SPRecycleBinOrderBy.Default;
                    SPRecycleBinItemCollection recycleitems = spweb.GetRecycleBinItems(objQuery);
                    foreach (SPRecycleBinItem item in recycleitems)
                    {
                        SPRecycleBinItemState state = item.ItemState;
                        if(item.ItemType == SPRecycleBinItemType.Folder)
                        {
                            long size = item.Size;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think this is as close as we can get. And it is an excellent approach. On my system an empty is 152 bytes.

Comment: Great.. you can create a check around this only.